# Riemann integration of discontinuous function

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, continuity

If 
$$
x_1(t) = \left\{
\begin{align}
0, & \quad t \ne 0 \\
1, & \quad t = 0
\end{align} \right.
\quad \quad
x_2(t) \equiv 0
$$
and $y_k(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t x_k(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau,~ k = 1, 2$

Is $y_1(t)$ identical with $y_2(t)$? What's the result of $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} y_1(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

The two are the same, and $\frac{dy_1}{dt}$ is identically zero. This does not contradict the (Riemann) fundamental theorem of calculus because the FTC requires the integrand to be continuous at the point where you differentiate.

Comment: @lan what does FTC stand for

Comment: @AlexanderZhang Edited.

Comment: then what's the definition of $d/dt y_1(0)$? Is it zero?

Comment: @AlexanderZhang The definition is the same as for any other function. Since $y_1$ is identically zero, its derivative is too. This means that $y_1'$ doesn't agree with $x_1$ at every point (only at continuity points of $x_1$).